# How to get value of label from within a Repeater on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my asp.net Repeater From within it there is a button. I want to get the value of lblFaulType in a string in code behind when i click Button1, How can I do that?I have tried many approaches but nothing working. Please give me your suggestions.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepterDetails" runat="server">  
<HeaderTemplate>  
<table style="border:1px solid #0000FF; width:500px" cellpadding="0">     
</HeaderTemplate>  
<ItemTemplate>  
<tr style="background-color:#EBEFF0">  
<td>  
<table style="background-color:#EBEFF0;border-top:1px dotted #df5015; width:500px" >  
<tr>  
<td >  
<strong><asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Fault Category: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  
<asp:Label ID="lblFaultType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fault Type") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>  
</td>
<td >  
<strong><asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Fault Description: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fault Description") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>  
</td> 
</tr> 
     <tr>  
<td >  
<strong><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Building: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>  
</td>
<td >  
<strong><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Floor: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  
<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FloorNo") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>  
</td> 
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
       <strong><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Room Number: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  
     <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RoomNumber") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>
     </td>
 </tr>
     <tr>  
<td ><strong><asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Created Time: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong> <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Time") %>'/></td>  
<td ><strong><asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Created Date: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>'/></td>  
</tr>
     <tr>  
<td ><strong><asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Start Status: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong>  <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("StartStatus") %>'/></td>  
<td ><strong><asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Assign Status: " Font-Bold="true"/></strong> <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("AssignStatus") %>'/></td>  
</tr>
</table>  
</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td >
 <asp:TextBox ID="lblComment"  runat="server" style="color:#000000;  font-weight: bold;" placeholder="Describe the fault here" Text='<%#Eval("Comment") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="70" Rows="6" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
 
</td>  
</tr>      
<tr>  
<td colspan="2" class="text-center"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Assing Fault" class="btn btn-success"  OnClick="Button1_Click" /> </td>  
</tr>  
</ItemTemplate>  
<FooterTemplate>  
</table>  
</FooterTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

We may need to see the CodeBehind for this page, and specifically the "Button1_Click" method (click event).

Now though, it appears as though you only have one of the labels with an ID of "lblFaultType" (maybe you misspelled that in your initial description.  Each of the other labels all carry sequentially numbered IDs (e.g. ID="Label1", ID="Label2", ID="Label3", etc), and your ClickEvent (the Button1_Click method) will need to iterate through those items to know 'which' label you are attempting to obtain a value from.

***Suggestion***: It may be better to apply a ClickEvent on each of the particular labels since it will have the ID there with it (a JScript/JQuery solution).

Answer (score 0):

This actually a GREAT question!

(in fact  good interview question)

Why?

Because how.net works for a gridview, listview, or a repeater?

They are ALL very similar.

If one has failed to grasp the “most basic” event model in .net, then suggestions to use JavaScript, or all kinds of wild approaches will be suggested (and they would get a failing mark in answering this question).

When using data bound controls that repeat data, then you can set a special command to trigger the Itemcommand event.

The attribute setting is called “CommandName”.

There are built in commands – and the command you use is important. However, "just" setting command name to somthing of your liking is sufficient in most cases.

This will CAUSE the ItemCommand event will fire. And once that occures, then you have "itemIndex" to point to any given row in the repeater (or gridview, or listview, or form view - the list goes on!!!).

So, add this to your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Assing Fault" 
    class="btn btn-success"  OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    CommandName = "Select" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Fault Type") %>'/>
```

Now, the the ItemCommand event, you can do this:

Protected Sub RepterDetails_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand

```
    Debug.Print("item command")

    Dim MyRow As RepeaterItem = e.Item

    Dim h As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblFaultType")
    Debug.Print(h.Text)

End Sub
```

Of course, since we set the CommandArguemnt to pass the value we want, then of course you can also do this:

```
  debug.print("Value of FaultType = " & e.CommandArgument)
```

So, be it a classic "data aware" control in .net? Well be it a listview, gridview, repeater, and MANY MORE, then use the built in "gift horse" features that of course expected this common need and solution.

And you can get the selected index into the repeater with this:

```
 Debug.Print(e.Item.ItemIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i found the answer at https://youtu.be/Oltxy1sGIds
So i did it like this:

```
RepeaterItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem; string type = +(item.FindControl("lblFaultType") as Label).Text;
```